# Pass LINQ model to view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Can we skip the defining model task and send the class represented in LINQ Data Context to the view? I notice that until now, most of my model is idenctical to / a composition of objects indeltical to what LINQ contain. I have not yet, however, find a way to transform LINQ to a type in the model.

If it is possible, we do not have to worry about compability of the programming language datatype with that of the DBMS and save some time as well.

Can you tell me if there is a way to implement it?

Comment: Are you trying to circumvent the use of the controller to do and do all your data manipulation in the view?

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass any type of object as the model for a view. If you don't know the data type (like if it's a LINQ-generated data type), you can always have a `@model dynamic` declaration in your view.

I would recommend *against* this approach, however. It is nice to have intellisense while editing your Razor views which can only come with having known data types. In addition, if you have precompiled views enabled for your project, the compiler can catch potential bugs in your view.

Answer (score 0):

There are *many many* ways to bypass using controller logic to create view data, and instead write that logic in the view.  However, why bother using ASP.Net MVC?  Might as well just use Webforms because that's basically what you are doing with additional routing overhead.

The biggest point of MVC are the [Single Reponsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Reusability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reusability).  If you're view is data aware and pulls data, it now has more responsiblity than just providing a view of a data, as it has to connect to the database and more.  Additionally, that view cannot be reused as easily because it's dependent on logic it's aware of to work properly, and if some other controller/action called it, it may not work properly in that context.